# Creating word file with images using objective c

Tags: html, ios, objective-c, image

I am trying to create a word file by writing simple `html` to .docx file for my iOS app. The `html` content has some img tags as well with absolute paths for images. The file created works fine when accessed from the same computer (accessing it from where simulator created it), but when I try to send the `docx` to someone else it is missing images. I am using the following code to create and write to file.

I want it to embed in my docx file. How do I achieve that?

```
NSString *userText = @"Hello, world!";

NSMutableString *html = [NSMutableString stringWithFormat:@"<html><body><h1>%@</h1><hr><br/> <img src=\"icon.png\"/></body></html>", userText];

NSString *docsFolder = NSSearchPathForDirectoriesInDomains(NSDocumentDirectory, NSUserDomainMask, YES)[0];

NSString *filename = [docsFolder stringByAppendingPathComponent:@"sample.docx"];

NSError *error;
[html writeToFile:filename atomically:NO encoding:NSUTF8StringEncoding error:&error];
if (error) {
    NSLog(@"Error occured");
}
```

Comment: I doubt very much that simply writing html content in a file with a `.docx` extension makes it a valid docx file.

Comment: In fact, as far as I know, docx files are really just zip archives, and this is how the document carries the images with it.

Answer (score 0):

The absolute path you are referring to is : icon.png\

This loads the image locally saved in the folder. To load image remotely, host your image and give an http path like : http://www.abcd.com/images/icon.png

Comment: I want it to embed in my docx file. How do I achieve that?

Comment: To create a docx file inside iOS app try using [libopc](http://libopc.codeplex.com/releases/view/70014)

Answer (score 0):

A [docx](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Office_Open_XML) is actually a ZIP file with a specific structure. You need to put your image into the ZIP file as well. Refer to [the specification](http://www.ecma-international.org/publications/standards/Ecma-376.htm) or [other documentation](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/aa338205(v=office.12).aspx). From a quick look, it seems you need to put the image into the same ZIP directory as your main HTML file.